# creating common function for case class lens shapeless - could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkSelectDynamicOptic

Tags: scala, generics, functional-programming, shapeless

I'm trying to create a common function to update my case class using shapeless lens:
but this fails could not find implicit value for parameter mkLens: shapeless.MkSelectDynamicOptic

```
import shapeless._
case class MyClass(a: String, b:String, c:Boolean)

val cl = MyClass("test", "test", false)

def update[T](fieldName: String, value:T): MyClass = {
  val l = lens[MyClass].selectDynamic(fieldName)
  l.set(cl)(value)
}

def updateA(value:String): MyClass = {
  update[String]("a", "new test")
}
```

but this work

```
def updateB(value: String): MyClass = {
  val l = lens[MyClass].selectDynamic("b")
  l.set(cl)(value)
}
```

As I understand compiler does not get any implicit for type T. Is there any way to create my own implicit for that, or may be there is better way to modify classes using shapeless.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are sticking to Shapeless rather than e.g. quicklens?

Comment: Also the problem in general is that `lens[MyClass].selectDynamic` is calling something which generates the code (it's NOT runtime reflection) and `fieldName` is used to generate the type of the returned value (compiler checks if it's `T`, it doesn't assume that it is what you said it is). Personally, I would just prefer to use Monocle or Quicklens to return some macro-generated optics.

Comment: Thank you @MateuszKubuszok, I was planning to use Shapeless for some other tasks, but yeah, may be it is better to use Monocle in this case. Any way if I end up using shapeless, i will update and put an answer here.